# Was the movie The Warriors (1979) based on a book?

Tags: book-adaptation, the-warriors

A friend claims that his father said that the movie *[The Warriors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080120/)* (1979) was based on a book.

Can anyone substantiate that?

Comment: I seem to recall writing before the film saying it was based on a story of soldiers from ancient Greece who had to fight their way back home.

Comment: Lolx. Two downvotes for the question, four upvotes for the answer. Welcome to S.E, it never ceases to raise a smile :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes.

The movie is *loosely* based on *The Warriors* (1965) by Sol Yurick.

It features a significantly *younger* protagonist (he's 12-14 if I recall) rather than the late teen / early 20's actors in the movie.

> The Warriors is a novel written by Sol Yurick and Illustrated by Frank Modell in 1965. It became the inspiration for the cult classic movie The Warriors. Compared to the movie, the novel takes a closer look at the concepts of sexuality, reputation, family, and survival.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_(Yurick_novel))</sup>